# Infinite tensor products and representations of anticommutation relations by Guichardet, A.

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

[Produits tensoriels infinis et représentations des relations d'anticommutation.](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1966_3_83_1_1_0.pdf)
I need this book which is written in French. I don't know if I should've posted here for the book or not but I tried a lot to find the translated version of it yet couldn't it. If anyone can help me to translate it into English from French.